# Emberjs How to access a class/constructor attributes without creating a model

Tags: javascript, class, ember.js, attributes

Is there a way to access a model class without creating a record from store and looking at his constructor ?

I have :

```
const feedback = this.store
                     .createRecord('feedback')
                     .get('constructor');
const attrs    = Ember.get(feedback, 'attributes')
                      ._keys
                      .list;
// attr = ["attr_1", "attr_2", ...]
```

Is there a proper way to find the same result without creating a record ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the good way to do it is to import the file into my controller/component.js

```
import Feedback form 'myApp/models/feedback'

...

const attrs = Ember.get(Feedback, 'attributes')
                   ._keys
                   .list;

// attr = ["attr_1", "attr_2", ...]
// Do not forget to use Ember.get and not to .get() on Feedback
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only correct way to do this is with the [`modelFor` function on the `store`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_modelFor).

Also do you realize that `._keys.list;` is totally private API? That just works on this specific `Map` polypill. There is a simple public API for this. use `.keys()` in combination with the spreads operator:

```
const attrs = [...store.modelFor('feedback').get('attributes').keys()]`
```

Comment: Yes, better approach. Thank you.
But it doesn't work. It need to use `Ember.get()`,

using `.get()` directly on the result of `modelFor()` doesn't works (it returns a function in fact)

Comment: using .keys() in combination with spreads operator on the result doesn't work neither.